# Power Query merge a subset of columns which name fit the criteria

Tags: powerquery

Power Query 2016 standalone

I have a table with columns like this

```
Market  | mapped Brand  |  mapped Subbrand  |

name    |  text 1       |  text 2
```

I need to concatenate columns that contain a word "mapped" into a new column

I'm trying this:

```
  Text.Combine(  List.FindText(Table.ColumnNames(Source), "mapped")  , " ")
```

and get result in every row as a concat of column names

```
mapped Brand mapped Subbrand
```

and I need a concat of their values

```
text 1 text 2
```

Comment: I am not by a computer now, but I would try wrapping each result of the text.combine with [], i.e. "[" & Text.Combine(..., "] & [" ) & "]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a list of the Columns which contain "mapped", then use that list to select the record fields you wish to combine

```
ColumnsToCombine = List.Select(Table.ColumnNames(Source), each Text.Contains(_, "mapped")),
#"Add Combined Column" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Merged", each Text.Combine(Record.FieldValues(Record.SelectFields(_,ColumnsToCombine)),", "))
```